# Failing to add a second '$or' expression

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to query a mongodb collection with two 'or' clauses via Java API. The following query works fine when run through any mongo client:

```
{
  $and : [{
    $or : [ { “field1” : “value1”}, {“field1” : “value2”}]
 },{
    $or : [ { “field2” : “value3”} , { “field2” : “value4”}]
 }]
}
```

But when I try to run this using Java API, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second '$or' expression specified as '$or : [ { “field1” : “value1”}, {“field1” : “value2”}]'. Criteria already contains '$or : [ { “field2” : “value3”} , { “field2” : “value4”}]'.
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.setValue(Criteria.java:640)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.getCriteriaObject(Criteria.java:573)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.createCriteriaList(Criteria.java:630)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.andOperator(Criteria.java:539)
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you can't do it with Java API.

Comment: Is there a way to run native query via Java client?

Comment: Problem is you have two top-level $or - that does not work with the map-like BasicDBObject. You need to wrap the top-level $or in an $and

Answer (score 11):

You can do it through Java API by

1) preparing a list of your 'or' criterias.

2) create new criteria object.

3) 'feed' the list created in (1) into the object created in (2),
using the criteria object's 'andOperator' method.

Something like this ->

```
    Query query = new Query();
    Map<String, String> params; // let's say this arrived with some values
    List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String k : params.keySet()) {
        String paramVal = params.get(k);
        switch (k) {
        case "someVal1":
            criterias.add(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("metadata.field1").is(paramVal),
                    Criteria.where("metadata.field2").is(paramVal)));

            break;
        case "someVal2":
            criterias.add(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("metadata.arrayField3").in(paramVal),
                    Criteria.where("metadata.arrayField4").in(paramVal),
                    Criteria.where("metadata.arrayField5").in(paramVal)));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    if (criterias.size() > 0){
        query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()])));
    }
```

Comment: But you cant use someVal1 and someVal2 together

Answer (score 5):

Try splitting that into an **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator. Let's break down the first **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** expression:

```
{
    "$or": [ 
        { "filed1" : "value1" }, 
        { "filed1" : "value2" }
    ]
}
```

This can be converted into an **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator as

```
{ "field1": { "$in": ["value1", "value2"] } }
```

Similarly

```
{
    "$or": [ 
        { "filed2" : "value3" }, 
        { "filed2" : "value4" }
    ]
}
```

can be expressed as

```
{ "field2": { "$in": ["value3", "value4"] } }
```

Combining the two expressions into one implicit AND query yields:

```
db.collection.find({
    "field1": { "$in": ["value1", "value2"] },
    "field2": { "$in": ["value3", "value4"] }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, upgrade to 3.x driver and stop using the old and obsolete handcrafted bson documents.

This works under 3.x:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        ) {
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("mycoll");

        Bson f = Filters.and(
            Filters.or(
                Filters.eq("field_a", "Test 1"),
                Filters.eq("field_a", "Test 2")
                ),
            Filters.or(
                Filters.eq("field_b", 1999),
                Filters.eq("field_b", 2000)
                )
            );            

        coll.find(f).forEach((Consumer<Document>) d -> System.out.println(d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,,

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().orOperator(
        Criteria.where("field1").regex(searchStr),
        Criteria.where("field2").regex(searchStr),
        Criteria.where("field3").regex(searchStr)));
List<XXX> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, XXX.class);
```